# CASE function order - T - SQL

Tags: t-sql, case

I m using a `CASE` function by i facing the following problem. Let s say i have the below data:

[image]

and these is my `CASE` function:

```
CASE
    WHEN [Country_Championship] LIKE 'England: National League North%' THEN 'England: National League North'
    WHEN [Country_Championship] LIKE 'England: National League South%' THEN 'England: National League South'
    WHEN [Country_Championship] LIKE 'England: National League%' THEN 'England: National League'
ELSE
END
```

if i do not order the `CASE` correct and i leave

`WHEN [Country_Championship] LIKE 'England: National League%' THEN 'England: National League`

at the beginning i all the lines recognizes as `England: National League` ignoring if more over there is a continuation of the string.

Is there a more orthodox - fast way to avoid the ordering?

Comment: A `CASE` **expression** is parsed in order; if the first clause is true, then the expression in the `WHEN` for the first clause will be returned. Ordering your clauses in a `CASE` expression is **important** as latter clauses will not be tested if one has already evaluated to True. This often means putting your most specific clauses first, and the least last.